# JavaScript Copy of Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to eliminate the minimum and maximum values from the below array and create 2 new arrays without the maximum and minimum values

```js
array = [4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
const indOmin = 0,
  indOm = 5

minArr = arr
maxArr = arr

minArr.forEach(cur => {
  if (arr.indexOf(cur) === indOmin) {
    minArr.splice(indOmin, 1)
  }
})

maxArr.forEach(cur => {
  if (arr.indexOf(cur) === indOm) {
    maxArr.splice(indOm, 1)
  }
})
```

When I use...

```js
console.log(minArr)
console.log(maxArr)
```

...then in both cases it returns `[6, 7, 8, 9]`.

But instead of...

```js
minArr = arr
maxArr = arr
```

...if I use...

```js
minArr = arr.map(cur => cur = cur)
maxArr = arr.map(cur => cur = cur)
```

... then the arrays return expected values.

```
[6, 7, 8, 9]
[4, 6, 7, 8]
```

Please help me understand why it doesn't work when I explicitly use the `=` operator (`minArr = arr`).

Comment: Those `forEach` and `indexOf` calls make no sense. If you're looping, you already know the index, no need to search for it. And since you're given the indices of min and max anyway, you don't need to do any looping at all - just call `splice` right away!

Comment: Also, `arr.map(cur => cur = cur)` is weird because the `cur = cur` does nothing (and just returns `cur`). It's the same as `arr.map(cur => cur)`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
minArr=arr; maxArr=arr;
```

To

```
minArr=[...arr]; maxArr=[...arr];
```

It doesn't work because array doesn't copy with = you had reference of same array in both minarr and maxarr.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question "why doesn't it work when I use `minArr = arr`".

Comment: updated reason above.

Comment: mark as answer please.

Comment: How can I do that? I don't see any option